# Remove server response header in IIS

Tags: security, iis

I've tried a couple of ways to remove the "server" information in the response header of an IIS application, some of them work well, but this one is not working:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry this is a browser link to Visual Studio. So this is resolved.